# <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu> appears in main.xml

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I am trying to create an Android project in Eclipse.  In the menu directory, I am trying to replace the content of the existing main.xml.  But

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>
```

keeps appearing as the very bottom line of my main.xml no matter how many times I delete it.  What is going on?  Is there some type of setting in Eclipse that I need to turn off.

And an error message appears in Eclipse beside the line that says:

"The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

I want to replace the main.xml with the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello" />
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/txtSpace" />
 <TextView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/txtFirstNumber" />
 <EditText
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
 android:id="@+id/EditText01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" > </EditText>
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/txtSpace" />
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/txtSecondNumber" />
 <Button 
 android:text="Multiply"
 android:id="@+id/Button01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"> </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to clean your project after deleting. It may be because of the main.xml contains the menu tag and that file is created for the options menu. So you can not keep the file empty. You will have to keep the menu tag.

Comment: With what content do you want to replace? Could you post the full file content in main.xml?

Comment: Cleaning the project, I no longer have that error message but instead have another error message: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Comment: I added what I want to replace the main.xml to the primary message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem as well.

Check your Eclipse settings in:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions | Perform the selected actions on save